# How to call xpath deep-equal in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to compare two (org.jdom2.Document) xml documents and plug them into my xpath expression.

```
String xpathExpression = "//[fn:deep-equal("+testDocument+","+ expectedDocument+")]";
```

This does not compile.  What is the proper syntax for this?

Also, I would expect this expression to return a boolean.  Should I use

```
List<Text> textValues = xpath.evaluate(testDocument);
```

to get the result?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-deep-equal returns a boolean and takes two sequences as its arguments. And `deep-equals` is XPath 2.0 or later, do you use JDOM together with an XPath 2.0 implementation?

Comment: The proper syntax is simply "deep-equal($x, $y)". Your syntax is wrong because (a) you want the answer to be a boolean, not some subset of some set of nodes that satisfies a boolean, and (b) if you did want a predicate to filter a node-set, the thing before the predicate must be a valid expression, and "//" on its own is not a valid expression.

Comment: @Michael Kay  I tried String xpathExpression = String.format("deep-equal(%s,%s)",testDocument,expectedDocument);  Both documents are populated.  I get an XPathSyntaxException: Caused by: class org.jaxen.saxpath.XPathSyntaxException: deep-equal([Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <policies [Namespace: http://policy.model.com/]/>]],[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <policies [Namespace: http://policy.model.com/]/>]]): 11: Unexpected '['

Comment: Jim: you can't expect the result of document.toString() to be something you can just concatenate into an XPath expression! And anyway, I don't think Jaxen supports XPath 2.0; you need to use Saxon or some other XPath 2.0 engine. Why aren't you doing what @MartinHonnen suggested?

Comment: @Michael Kay I was just trying your suggestion first.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon in the PE and EE edition has support for doing XPath 2.0 evaluation against JDOM nodes, so you could write an XPath expression `deep-equal(., $doc2)` where the context node is the first document and the variable `doc2` is bound against the second document:

```
Processor proc = new Processor(true);
proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration().registerExternalObjectModel(JDOM2ObjectModel.getInstance());

DocumentBuilder db = proc.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc1 = new Document(new Element("root", "This is a test"));
Document doc2 = doc1.clone();

XdmNode xdmDoc1 = db.wrap(doc1);
XdmNode xdmDoc2 = db.wrap(doc2);

XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
xpath.declareVariable(new QName("doc2"));

XPathExecutable xx = xpath.compile("deep-equal(., $doc2)");

XPathSelector sel = xx.load();
sel.setContextItem(xdmDoc1);
sel.setVariable(new QName("doc2"), xdmDoc2);

XdmItem result = sel.evaluateSingle();

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by converting the xml files to strings, then used org.custommonkey.**xmlunit** to diff the strings.

*pom*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency
```

*test*

```
...
String test = xmlToString(testXml);
String expected = xmlToString(expectedXml);
...
Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(expected, test);
assertTrue(xmlDiff.similar());
...
```

*convert xml to string*

```
private String xmlToString(File xml)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xml));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
        sb.append(line.trim());
    }
    br.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

*the diff can be customized*

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(expected, test);
xmlDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new DifferenceListener() {
    @Override
    public int differenceFound(Difference diff) {
        System.err.println("called: " + diff);
        int diffResult = RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;

        //ignore a node difference
        if(diff.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().getParentNode().getNodeName().contains("myNodeName")){
            skippedComparison(diff.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().getParentNode(), diff.getTestNodeDetail().getNode().getParentNode());
            diffResult = RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
        } 

        return diffResult;
    }
    @Override
    public void skippedComparison(Node arg0, Node arg1) {}
});

assertTrue(xmlDiff.similar());
```